# Why is icon on iOS 8.1 blurry but on 7.1 is OK

Tags: ios, icons

I am wondering, why is the same icon blurry on iOS 8.1, but sharp on iOS 7.1.

Please consider this two images:

iOS 7.1:
[image]

iOS 8.1
[image]

UPDATED:
I finally found **solution**. I am using Apache Cordova project - all icon formats are set in config.xml. At first build, icons were all OK. But icon design had been changed, so I had to change all icon source files. After this change, the blurry icons appeared at iOS 8 devices. I solved this using Xcode and its project settings of App Icons and Launch Images. I tried to manually drag and drop icon source files into the App icon list in Xcode. And after that, all icons are OK again. It seems to some issue connected with Apache Cordova config.xml settings of icon files.

Comment: Are these versions of iOS both running on the same iPhone model? Is one retina and one non retina?

Comment: This images are from iOS simulator - iPhone 5s with different OS versions, but I discovered the same behaviour also in case of real devices - or exactly - I do not have real device with iOS 7.1, but on iPhone 4S (retina) or iPhone 5s (also retina), both running iOS 8.1, the icon image is blurry.

Comment: do you have a vector version of the icon you can use? a pdf? if you try that it might work

Comment: I have used PSD App Icon Template 4, for generating iOS icons. Of course, the source file was imported into the template from the PDF vector source file.